# Changing the input stream for the command line in C# from "Csvmidi.exe file.text file.midi" to "Csvmidi.exe inputString file.midi"

Tags: c#, visual-studio, file, command-line, system.diagnostics

Using the process class in System.Diagnostics, I have been able to run an executable file in a program, but I want to generate text in my program and pass it to the executable to convert straight to the output file (the .midi) rather than generating a file and then converting the file.  Is this possible?  If not, what's an easy way to, say, convert the text I generate in my program into a file, convert the file into the output file, and then have that file deleted?  Executable sourse:  http://www.fourmilab.ch/webtools/midicsv/

```
using System.Diagnostics

Process converter= new Process();
converter.StartInfo.FileName = "Csvmidi.exe";
converter.StartInfo.Arguments = "file.midi file.midi";
converter.Start();
```

For example, let's say I have a string, inputText, that matches the contents of the file, file.text.

```
string inputText = "0, 0, Header, 1, 1, 480\n" +
               "1, 0, Start_track\n" +
               "1, 0, Title_t, \"Close Encounters\"\n" +
               "1, 0, Text_t, \"Sample for MIDIcsv Distribution\"\n" +
               "1, 0, Copyright_t, \"This file is in the public domain\"\n" +
               "1, 0, Tempo, 500000\n" +
               "1, 0, End_track\n" +
               "2, 0, Start_track\n" +
               "2, 0, Instrument_name_t, \"Church Organ\"\n" +
               "2, 0, Program_c, 1, 19\n" +
               "2, 0, Note_on_c, 1, 79, 81\n" +
               "2, 960, Note_off_c, 1, 79, 0\n" +
               "2, 960, Note_on_c, 1, 81, 81\n" +
               "2, 1920, Note_off_c, 1, 81, 0\n" +
               "2, 1920, Note_on_c, 1, 77, 81\n" +
               "2, 2880, Note_off_c, 1, 77, 0\n" +
               "2, 2880, Note_on_c, 1, 65, 81\n" +
               "2, 3840, Note_off_c, 1, 65, 0\n" +
               "2, 3840, Note_on_c, 1, 72, 81\n" +
               "2, 4800, Note_off_c, 1, 72, 0\n" +
               "2, 4800, End_track\n" +
               "0, 0, End_of_file";
```

Can I pass this string to the executable instead of the text file of this?

**Edit:  I had a friend help me by making a temporary file to copy the text to to run the process before deleting it.  Thanks for all the help, everyone!**

Comment: If this `converter.exe` takes only input and output file paths as arguments, then you will have to create files.

Comment: It says that the converter.exe can read the input from standard input if no file is specified, so I guess that would mean entering the values slowly on the command line.  Does this mean its possible I can just pass the values as one string assuming it's formatted correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this `converter.exe` takes only input and output file paths as arguments, then you will have to create files.

As you say, it can read the input from standard input. Assuming that input data is formatted correctly, you can start a process and write to its stdin directly:

```
Process p = new Process();

p.StartInfo.FileName = "converter.exe";
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;

p.Start();

p.StandardInput.Write(inputText);
p.StandardInput.Close();

p.WaitForExit();
p.Close();
```

In this example, I assume that it still creates an output file. If in case of using standard input, it can output only in standard output, then you will have to use `p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true` and read `p.StartInfo.StandardOutput` as well.

Comment: p.StartInfo.StandardOutput didn't work for me, so I tried Console.WriteLine(outputFileName); to write the standard output to the console and I don't think the file appeared anywhere.  I tried wihtout the standardOutput lines, and I got the same thing.  Am I doing something wrong to not get the file to appear?

Comment: @Ignify Using external executables is like taking something from a black box. Check how it works wnen you simply open a file and enter your data. It should generate a file. Try applying `/?` or `-?` key to get the documentation on this executable.

Comment: I don't think any of those work.  They're listed on the original [site](http://www.fourmilab.ch/webtools/midicsv/), but nothing has helped me.  Your code doesn't cause me an error, but I can't seem to get an output file from it for some reason.  I can confirm that this program does require standard output though.